# Save a JSON from AWS Lambda to AWS S3 with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to save a JSON File from AWS Lambda to S3.
(to be more precise: I want to create a new file `'supertest.json'` containing the 'data' inside the S3 bucket `'gpiocontroll-XYZ'` )

The Lambda function looks like this:

```
'use strict'

const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3();

//const fs = require('fs');

function saveJSONtoS3(data){
    console.log('SAVEJSON', data);

    var params = {
        Bucket: 'gpiocontroll-XYZ', // your bucket name,
        Key: 'test.txt', // path to the object you're looking for
        Body: data
    }

    s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
        // Handle any error and exit
        if (err)
        console.log('ERROR', err);
        else {
            console.log('UPLOADED SUCCESS');
        }
        console.log('INSIDE FUNCTION');
    });

    console.log('END')
}

module.exports = {
    saveJSONtoS3 : saveJSONtoS3
}
```

The log on Lambda looks like:

```
2017-12-27T20:04:29.382Z    255d436d-eb41-11e7-b237-1190c4f33d2d    SAVEJSON {"table":[{"pin":"1","state":"aus"}]}
2017-12-27T20:04:29.402Z    255d436d-eb41-11e7-b237-1190c4f33d2d    END
END RequestId: 255d436d-eb41-11e7-b237-1190c4f33d2d
REPORT RequestId: 255d436d-eb41-11e7-b237-1190c4f33d2d  Duration: 362.29 ms Billed Duration: 400 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 43 MB
```

So it seems like everything is fine but the **s3.putObject** function just don't get triggered. Lambda and S3 are both in the same region. The S3 is public with an IAM user. Do I need to log in in the Lambda function somehow?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no `s3.putObject` call there

Comment: Sorry. Just updated the example code.

Comment: That is not an AWS Lambda function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [@dashmug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252647/dashmug) said, your example is *not* a Lambda function.

You **must** have `exports.handler` in your file somewhere unless specified in the function configuration.

All Lambda functions start by calling `exports.handler` with `( event, context, callback )` parameters. These include the data of the `event` or action, some additional `context`, and a success/fail `callback`.

Here is what you are looking for:

**Update:** changed `S3.putObject` Promise wrapped function to `S3.putObject().promise()` per [@dashmug’s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252647/dashmug) recommendation.

> Requires AWS SDK for JavaScript (v2.3.0 - March 31 2016 or later)

```
'use strict';

const
    AWS = require( 'aws-sdk' ),
    S3  = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = ( event, context, callback ) => {
    console.log( `FUNCTION STARTED: ${new Date()}` );

    S3.putObject( {
         Bucket: 'gpiocontroll-XYZ',
         Key: 'test.txt',
         Body: 'stuff'
    } )
         .promise()
         .then( () => console.log( 'UPLOAD SUCCESS' ) )
         .then( () => callback( null, 'MISSION SUCCESS' ) )
         .catch( e => {
            console.error( 'ERROR', e );
            callback( e );
         } );
};
```

**Note:** you *must* give the Lambda function IAM permissions to the S3 Bucket you are trying to access. In the case above, your IAM role should look something like this:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [ "s3:PutObject" ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::gpiocontroll-XYZ/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: The Lambda function doesn't have to be named `handler`. I usually name them clearly (e.g. `api`, `graphql`, `worker`, etc.). Also, the use of `module.exports` is fine (vs. simply `exports`).

Comment: You can get rid of your Promise wrapper by using `s3.putObject(params).promise()` instead. It will look much cleaner.

Comment: Oh ya! Forgot they added that. Thank you

Comment: @dashmug and iSkore first of all: Thanks a lot. But the function I posted seems to work. (see the log). The 'data' and the 'END' are getting logged. I also get errors if something in the params is wrong. The only strange thing is that I don't get any logs out of the putObject function...

Comment: Just checked your suggestion and get the exact same log: `2017-12-28T07:31:02.663Z 0dee436e-eba1-11e7-a45b-17d92e2998bb SAVEJSON {"table":[{"pin":"1","state":"aus"}]}
2017-12-28T07:31:03.146Z 0dee436e-eba1-11e7-a45b-17d92e2998bb END` he just skipped the 'putObject'.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: @luckybusted How did you invoke that function to get that log? How did you specify your `data` argument? If you got it by using the AWS console, then that will still not work.

Comment: If you copy and past that exact function above into Lambda, you should at least get the log `FUNCTION STARTED: 2017-12-28T11:35:25.769Z`

Comment: This worked for me. I love how simple and readable the code is. That's rare among online examples.

Comment: [@mamun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5691932/mamun) Thank you! I like spacing in my code. Lots of space!
Spread the love, `letsstopmakingcodelikethis` (_lets stop making code like this_) we learn as children to read books with lots of spacing between paragraphs and words. Code should be the same!